# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x+x^3}-x)\ln(\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}}{2\sqrt x +3})}{x\arctan x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x+x^3}-x)\ln(\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}}{2\sqrt x +3})}{x\arctan x}$$
I think,it would be useful to start with simplifying the first term in the numerator as $(\sqrt{x+x^3}-x)=x^{{3\over2}}$ and leaving the denominator untouched.Then,i have to just work on the remaining term,but I can't figure out a way to not have $\ln1=0$

Comment: As $x\to+\infty$ $x$ is negligible with respect to $x^3$ and it becomes $\sqrt {x^3}=x^{{3\over2}}$ and then isn't $x$ negligible with respect to $x^{{3\over2}}$?

Comment: While I'm sure you need the steps to get to the answer, it sometimes helps if one knows the answer which in this case is $-3/\pi$.

Comment: Just because they are asymptotically equivalent does not mean they are simply equal.

Comment: @JimB I know the answer as well,thanks anyway.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art they'are indeed not equal but why exactly can't i use this approximation in this case?I have used this kind of approximation in similar situations.

Comment: When did we say you couldn't use their asymptotic equivalence?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt If I can use equivalence, what was the point in saying "Just because they are asymptotically equivalent does not mean they are simply equal" then?

Comment: To point out that you wrote they were equal when they are not?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  I think,what I meant would be clear to someone willing to help.

Comment: Whether or not we knew what you meant was aside from the point. We saw an issue with what you wrote and are trying to help you fix it. I do not believe ignoring what may be a misconception is helpful, and the only reasons I am still having this conversation with you are because the issue is still there and you seem to be ignoring it as "it's clear what I meant to say, so I'm not going to fix it." They are asymptotically equivalent, which means you can use them for the limit, but this does not mean they are equal, so you shouldn't write them as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x+x^3}-x)\ln\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}}{2\sqrt x +3}}{x\arctan x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x^3\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}}{2\sqrt x +3}-1+1\right)}{(\sqrt{x+x^3}-x)x\arctan x}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}}{2\sqrt x +3}-1\right)}{(\sqrt{x+x^3}-x)\arctan x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x^2(4x+1-4x-12\sqrt{x}-9)}{(2\sqrt x +3)(\sqrt{4x+1}+2\sqrt x +3)(\sqrt{x+x^3}-x)\arctan x}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{-12-\frac{8}{\sqrt{x}}}{\left(2 +\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\left(\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{x}}+2 +\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\arctan x}=$$
$$=\frac{-12}{2\cdot4\cdot1\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}}=-\frac{3}{\pi}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x+x^3}-x)\ln(\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}}{2\sqrt x +3})}{x\arctan x}=\dfrac2\pi\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x+x^3}-x)\ln(\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}}{2\sqrt x +3})}x$$

Set $x=1/h^2,h\to0^+$

$$\sqrt{x+x^3}-x=\sqrt{\dfrac1{h^2}+\dfrac1{h^6}}-\dfrac{1}{h^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h^4}-h}{h^3}\text{ and }\dfrac{\sqrt{4x+1}}{2\sqrt{x}+3}= \dfrac{\sqrt{4+h^2}}{2+3h} $$

$$\dfrac{\pi I}2=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{h^2(\sqrt{1+h^4}-h)}{h^3}\ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{4+h^2}}{2+3h}\right)$$

$2\ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{4+h^2}}{2+3 h}\right)=\ln\dfrac{4+h^2}{(2+3h)^2}=\ln\left(1-\dfrac{12h}{(2+3h)^2}\right)$

$$\pi I=-\lim_{h\to0^+}(\sqrt{1+h^4}-h)\cdot\lim_{h\to0^+}\left(\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\ln\left(1-\dfrac{12h}{(2+3h)^2}\right)}{-\dfrac{12h}{(2+3h)^2}}\right)\cdot\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\dfrac{12h}{(2+3h)^2}}h=-1\cdot1\cdot\dfrac{12}4$$